# Remove null elements from array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have  my html like

```
  <input  type="text" class="form-control PaperSupply">` 
  <input  type="text" class="form-control PaperSupply">`
 <input  type="text" class="form-control PaperConsum">
 <input  type="text" class="form-control PC">
```

multiple inputs for same value papersupply and PaperConsum,
in javascript i am creating an array for same value using map function like this

```
 var paperSupply = $('.PaperSupply').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get(); 
 var PaperConsum= $('.PaperConsum').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

now in json i want if any element of these array is null remove that element from array.

for example:

```
{"paperSupply":["","2","3","","5"],"paperConsum":["1","","4","5","6"]}
```

if this is json from above code,
then i want above json like this,

```
{"paperSupply":["2","3","5"],"paperConsum":["","4","6"]}
```

if any index of paperSupply is null it should be null then same index for second array should also be remove .

this is demo fiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eve44jhf/)

Answer (score 2):

You can return undefined from [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to ignore the empty values.

> Within the callback function, this refers to the current DOM element
>   for each iteration. The function can return an individual data item or
>   an array of data items to be inserted into the resulting set. If an
>   array is returned, the elements inside the array are inserted into the
>   set. **If the function returns null or undefined, no element will be
>   inserted.**

```
var paperSupply = $('.PaperSupply').map(function () {
    return $(this).val().trim() || undefined; //use trim only if you want to discard inputs with space only
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5q23183/)

---

Update

```
var PaperConsum = [],
    $PaperConsums = $('.PaperConsum');
var paperSupply = $('.PaperSupply').map(function (i, el) {
    var value = $(this).val().trim(); //use trim only if you want to discard inputs with space only
    if (value) {
        PaperConsum.push($PaperConsums.eq(i).val() || '');
        return value;
    }
}).get();

console.log(paperSupply, PaperConsum)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5q23183/2/)

Comment: thanks for answer, but you are only removing element from array, not removing second array element from same index. if paperSupply[0] is null then paperConsum[0] should also be null

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter:

```
$('.PaperSupply').map(function(){
    return $(this).val().trim();
}).get().filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but you are only removing element from array, not removing second array element from same index. if paperSupply[0] is null then paperConsum[0] should also be null